# How to read a csv file with python

Tags: python, csv

I'm trying to read a csv file but it doesn't work.
I can read my csv file but when I see what I read, there where white space between values.

Here is my code

```
# -*- coding: iso-8859-1 -*-
import sql_db, tmpl_macros, os
import security, form, common

import csv

class windows_dialect(csv.Dialect):
    """Describe the usual properties of unix-generated CSV files."""
    delimiter = ','
    quotechar = '"'
    doublequote = 1
    skipinitialspace = 0
    lineterminator = 'n'
    quoting = csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL


def reco(d):
 cars = {210:'"', 211:'"', 213:"'", 136:'à', 143:'è', 142:'é'}
 for c in cars:
  d = d.replace(chr(c),cars[c])
 return d

def page_process(ctx):
 if ctx.req_equals('catalog_send'):
  if 'catalog_file' in ctx.locals.__dict__:
   contenu = ctx.locals.catalog_file[0].file.read()
   #contenu.encode('')
   p = csv.reader(contenu, delimiter=',')
   inserted = 0
   modified = 0
   (cr,db) = sql_db.cursor_get()
   for line in p:
    if line:
     logfile = open('/tmp/test.log', 'a')
     logfile.write(line[0])
     logfile.write('\n')
     logfile.write('-----------------------------\n')
     logfile.close()
```

Comment: +1 for 'unix-generated CSV files' (showing that Excel isn't the *only* way)

Comment: your indentation is inconsistent.

Comment: What does "whitespace between values" mean?  The file has whitespace in it?  The values that `csv` got from the file have whitespace around them?  Your line terminator is wrong, BTW.  It should be `\n` not `n`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I read and write CSV files with Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41585078/how-do-i-read-and-write-csv-files-with-python)

Answer (score 7):

I prefer to use numpy's genfromtxt rather than the standard csv library, because it generates numpy's recarray, which are clean data structures to store data in a table-like object.

```
>>> from numpy import genfromtxt
>>> data = genfromtxt(csvfile, delimiter=',', dtype=None)
# data is a table-like structure (a numpy recarray) in which you can access columns and rows easily
>>> data['firstcolumn']
<content of the first column>
```

---

EDIT: This answer is quite old. While numpy.genfromtxt, nowadays most people would use pandas:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> pd.read_csv(csvfile)
```

This has the advantage of creating pandas.DataFrame, which is a better structure for data analysis.

Comment: Don't you need to use `names=True` in `genfromtxt()` to get `data['firstcolumn']` to work?

Answer (score 2):

If you have control over the data, use tab-delimited instead::

```
import csv
import string

writer = open('junk.txt', 'wb')
for x in range(10):
    writer.write('\t'.join(string.letters[:5]))
    writer.write('\r\n')
writer.close()
reader = csv.reader(open('junk.txt', 'r'), dialect='excel-tab')
for line in reader:
    print line
```

This produces expected results.

A tip for getting more useful feedback:  Demonstrate your problem through self-contained and complete example code that doesn't contain extraneous and unimportant artifacts.

Answer (score 0):

You don't do anything with the dialect you've defined. Did you mean to do this:

```
csv.register_dialect('windows_dialect', windows_dialect)
p = csv.reader(contenu, dialect='windows_dialect')
```

Also not sure what the `reco` function is for.